# TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, nodejs

I have  [this contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d1C6910f5Ae8acb3B56efE9681c1b6Ccfb49Bb4#code) and deployed it to my local client (ganache gui) and its abi.json file (of solc compiler generated). The third file is param.txt which contains encoded functions with arguments which then saved into an array and takes elements one by one . `[0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f0,0x25468f680000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,0xed2b5a3c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000]`
the first one is about constructor with its arguments and from second to onward are some of its encoded functions with arguments. My task is to send these encoded functions with parameters to that contract (deployed at localhost - Ganache GUI). My code works for contract whose constructor s without arguments, but give error for constructor with arguments.

**Here is my code:**

```
 async function dep(r) {

    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(myAbi[r]);

      for(i=0; i<1; i++) {

      if(constructorParams[i]=='0x'){ // checking first element of above array is 0x (means constructor with no arguments).. 
// if this true, then my code works, if constructor have some arguments then error
        params = {
          data: '0x' + myBin[r]
      };
      }
      else
      {
        params = {
          //  data: '0x' + myBin[r]+constructorParams[i]
          data: '0x' + myBin[r],
          arguments: constructorParams[1]
      };
      }


    const transaction = contract.deploy(params); // here is error 
    console.log(transaction)
    const options = {
        data: transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas: await transaction.estimateGas({from: account1})
    };

    const signed = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, privateKey1);
    receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
    console.log(`Contract deployed at address: ${receipt.contractAddress}`);
    }
```

I just want to know following two things;

1. In above encoded array, is constructor encoded properly or not ?

   2. If enconded constructor is true, then why this error ?
   3. i have taken `bin` .as myAbi from json file, should I have to take this `bin` or should i have to take `bin-runtime` to deploy
      contract.

**Here is my error:**

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object
    at Contract.deploy (C:\Users\aa\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\src\index.js:510:33)
    at dep (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\deploy - fromsFuzz.js:133:30)
    at main (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\deploy - fromsFuzz.js:198:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\deploy - fromsFuzz.js:214:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
(node:20300) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:20300) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**UPDATE:** I have change `argument : constructorParams[1]` to  `arguments: [constructorParams[1]]`, but then my encoded constructor treated as one argument which shows following error;

```
Error: Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 1 expected 2!
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
constructorParams[1] = 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f0
```

**UPDATE 3:** 
my constructor in contract which i want to call is =   `constructor(address moneyMarket, address liquidator) LiquidationChecker(moneyMarket, liquidator) {}`. Now, anyone can tell me that whether in above **constructorParams**, i am encoding these two addressess (moneyMarket and liquidator) correctly or not ?

**UPDATE 4:**
if i deploy my above contract using sendTransaction like below;

```
if(constructorParams[0]==''){
      params = '0x' + myBin[r]
    }
    else
    {
        params= '0x' + myBin[r]+constructorParams[0]
    }

try {
  await web3.eth.sendTransaction(
    {from:account1,
    data: params
        }, function(err, receipt) {console.log(receipt)});
} catch (error) {
  console.log(" ERROR !", error); 
}
```

then it give following error;

```
Error: Returned error: base fee exceeds gas limit
```

Comment: The bottom part looks like a piece of code that I gave you (?). Which line in your code triggers this error?

Comment: BTW, unless `constructorParams[1]` is an array, you should change `arguments: constructorParams[1]` to `arguments: [constructorParams[1]]`.

Comment: yes, it was your code, i already mentioned the line, see code where ' const transaction = contract.deploy(params); // here is error'

Comment: i have changed , but it gives this error .. Error: Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 1 expected 2!... Can you confirm my encoded constructor with parameters is true ?

Comment: also i have provided update as per your comments. see my update

Comment: I cannot investigate further, because I have no idea what's inside `constructorParams[1]`, and you haven't bothered to post it!

Comment: taken from encoded array .. constructorParams[1] = 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f0

Comment: And what does your contract's constructor look like?

Comment: i have provided contract link , its take two parameter... but i am not sure, what wrong in my encoded constructor..

Comment: Yeah, well you should post the relevant info directly in here, not in links or images.

Comment: Anyway, allow me to guess that your constructor takes 2 input parameters (which would explain the error that you're getting, and also raise up the question - what exactly were you expecting when you called it with 1 input parameter?).

Comment: it will become long question... Should I update again to include contract code ??

Comment: Well, I thought you were linking directly to the code, but now I see that you're linking to etherscan, where one has to scroll down searching for this specific constructor. Keep in mind that etherscan bundles the source code of ALL contracts and interfaces that the deployed contract depends on, so there could be several constructors in there, and more generally speaking, a ton of code. So yes, you should definitely post it here, and ONLY the relevant information (the constructor's code, or even just its prototype I suppose).

Comment: In any case, as I've guessed in the comment above - if this constructor takes two input arguments, then your code would obviously not work, since you are passing only one.

Comment: but i think, encoding parameters (whether they are 2, 3 or more ) , eventually become only one long string. As per ABI specs https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.13/abi-spec.html , you can see the example.. so, for solc compiler 0.4.25 such ABI specs for encoding is different or same as 0.5.13 ...

Comment: `deploy` takes native parameters, not encoded ones.

Comment: so any solution for my use case scenario ?

Comment: Well, I didn't quite look into it beyond the immediate "compilation" error that you need to attend to, i.e., passing to `deploy` an array of two input parameters which represent the types of the two input parameters that your constructor takes (which you haven't posted here as of yet BTW!).

Comment: i have posted my constructor (see my update 3), btw. if i deploy by sendTransaction then this error occurred ... Returned error: base fee exceeds gas limit

Comment: `sendTransaction` takes an abi-encoded transaction, so you should ask yourself what transaction exactly you have encoded inside `params`...